# Не получается вывести значение из массива

Tags: php, массивы

Есть массив

> $key = var_export($matches[0])

в котором получаем `(array ( 0 => 'Х', 1 => 116, ))`, но не получается вывести из него значения [0] и [1].
Пробую, например: `echo $key[0]`.

Подскажите, что делаю не так (

Comment: `echo $matches[0][0];` Прежде чем использовать какую-либо функцию - удостоверьтесь что вы понимаете что она делает.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте:

```
var_dump($matches[0]);
```

Если нужно одного элемента, то `echo($matches[0][0])`